# Structure of sem_t and implementation of semaphores

Tags: c, linux, posix, semaphore

In C programming language  why do we need a special sem_t type for defining the semaphore? Couldn't that been an integer?How is sem_t defined? How is the functions sem_post and sem_wait implemented?
EDIT:An example implementation like GNU C library will be great.

Comment: The `sem_t` type is deliberate undefined as it's up to the specific implementation how to implement it. If you want to find out about _one_ implementation you could download the source to the [GNU C library](http://www.gnu.org/software/libc/) and read the source yourself.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Semaphores are OS kernel managed objects, so sem_t will be OS-specific, as will be the signal/wait calls since they also necessarily call into the OS kernel.

Usually, the semaphores are implemented by a unit count and a queue for any waiting threads.

Comment: Isn't the semaphores in linux(i.e one which has sem_wait ,sem_post...)  implemented in the user space?

Comment: @PaulDaviesC I don't see how it could be.  sem_wait() has to block the caller if the semaphore is empty, and that requires kernel support.